Join 3 tables without table 2 and 3 overlapping
I have 3 tables.  Table 1 has an ID field in it.  Tables 2 and 3 have an FK pointing back to table 1's ID.  I need to get all data from all 3 tables without tables 2 and 3 showing up in each others' rows. Table 2 and 3 have different schemas.
So, assuming I had only 1 row in table 1, 3 rows in table 2, and 5 rows in table 3, I want to get back 3 + 5 = 8 rows.
I have tried joining these a number of ways.  This is the last thing I tried, but it did not do what I am looking for.
SELECT *
FROM Payments p
left outer join Notices n on n.PaymentID = p.ID
left outer join Checks c on c.PaymentID = p.ID
where p.ID = 154;

Given
Payments
ID   Name
154  Pay1

Notices
ID   PaymentID   NoticeNumber   Due
1    154         A2             23.45
2    154         A4             10.00
3    154         A5             10.00

Checks
ID   PaymentID    Paid
1    154          43.45

I want this...
ID   Name   NoticeNumber   Due     Paid
154  Pay1   A2             23.45   null
154  Pay1   A4             10.00   null
154  Pay1   A5             10.00   null
154  Pay1   null           null    43.45


Please create a minimal, reproducible example, that demonstrate which rows you want back (not just how many), including how to prioritize if there are rows in both notices and checks for the same ID.

Try full join

Also try a union of 2 queries  1=payment with Notice,  2=payment with checks

@BartMcEndree I thought of that, but I don't know how to handle the different schemas between table 2 and 3.  I just figured this out!  Thanks, Bart!

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

SELECT p.ID, Name,n.NoticeNumber,   n.Due,     NULL as Paid
FROM Payments p
INNER join Notices n on n.PaymentID = p.ID
where p.ID = 154

UNION ALL

SELECT p.ID, Name, NULL as NoticeNumber,   NULL as Due,     c.Paid
FROM Payments p
INNER join Checks c on c.PaymentID = p.ID
where p.ID = 154

fiddle



ID
Name
NoticeNumber
Due
Paid




154
Pay1
A2
23.4500
null


154
Pay1
A4
10.0000
null


154
Pay1
A5
10.0000
null


154
Pay1
null
null
43.4500




I'm not sure if i unserstand you correctly, but i think you want all rows from table 2 and 3 and both of them joined to table1.
If so, you just have to union results from selects on both tables (2+3)
SELECT * FROM (
(
SELECT p.ID AS paymentID, n.ID as entityID, 'notice' AS entityType FROM notices n LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.ID=n.paymentFK
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT p.ID as paymentID, c.ID as entityID, 'check' as entityType FROM checks c LEFT JOIN payment p ON p.ID=c.checks.paymentFK
)
) data
WHERE data.paymentID=154

